# error with regex matching over 2 source files, expected string or buffer

Tags: python, regex

so I would like to from a `input.txt` file, create a two dictionaries

for example, here is sample of the `input.txt` file

```
@. VAR @first=Billy
@. VAR @last=Bob
@. PRINT VARS
@. VAR @petName=Gato
@. VAR @street="1234 Home Street"
@. VAR @city="New York" 
@. VAR @state=NY 
@. VAR @zip=21236 
@. VAR @title=Dr.
@. PRINT VARS
@. FORMAT LM=5  JUST=LEFT
@. PRINT FORMAT
```

so `VAR @varName=value`

i.e in the case of `@first=Billy` you would get something like `varDict = {"first": "Billy"}` right?
Now I wanna know how to do that thru the entire file

There are two dictionaries that I would need to populate, one for the variables, and one for FORMAT, which just holds values, doesn't actually do anything for now.

As far as a desired output, In the input file, there are commands that when read, will trigger to either add variables to the directory, or print that directory, or add to the format directory. I would use the pprint function like this `pprint.pprint(varDict , width=30)` and would output something like this

```
{'first': 'Billy',
'last': 'Bob'}
{'city': 'New York',
'first': 'Billy',
 'last': 'Bob',
'petName': 'Gato',
'state': 'NY',
'street': '1234 Home Street',
'title': 'Dr.',
'zip': '21236'}
{'BULLET': 'o',
'FLOW': 'YES',
'JUST': 'LEFT',
'LM': '5',
'RM': '80'}
```

Unfortunately i keep getting errors all over the place on the driver and source file

`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'groups'`

`TypeError: expected string or buffer`

`Driver.py`

```
input=(sys.argv[1])

# Group 1. VAR
# Group 2. @first=Mae or JUST=RIGHT FLOW=NO
# pass Group 2 as atString
regexSearch = re.compile(r'^@. ([A-Z]+) (.*)', re.MULTILINE)
regexPrintVAR = re.compile(r'^@\.\s*PRINT\s(VARS)', re.MULTILINE)
regexPrintFORMAT = re.compile(r'^@\.\s*PRINT\s(FORMAT)',re.MULTILINE)
regexERRCheck = re.compile(r'^@\.\s*FORMAT\s+BAD', re.MULTILINE)

varDictionary = dict()
formatDictionary = {"FLOW":"YES", "LM":"1", "RM":"80","JUST":"LEFT","BULLET":"o"}

file = open(input, "r")
while True:
    inputLine = file.readline()
    matchObj = regexSearch.search(inputLine)
    command, atString = matchObj.groups()

    if command == "VAR":
        setVariable(atString,varDictionary)

    if command == "FORMAT":
        formatListERR = regexERRCheck.search(inputLine)
        if formatListERR != None:
            print("*** Not a recognizable command")
            line = file.readline()
        setFormat(atString, formatDictionary)

    if command == "PRINT":
        printVARObj = regexPrintVAR.search(inputLine)
        printFormatObj = regexPrintFORMAT.search(inputLine)

        if printVARObj != None:
            pprint.pprint(varDictionary, width=30)
        elif printFormatObj != None:
            pprint.pprint(formatDict, width=30)
    inputLine = file.readline()

file.close()
```

`importFileIUse.py`

```
# The atString is the remainder of the string after the VAR or FORMAT key word.
varDictionary = dict()
formatDictionary = {"FLOW":"YES", "LM":"1", "RM":"80","JUST":"LEFT","BULLET":"o"}

def setFormat(atString,formatDictionary):
    regexFormat = re.compile(r'((?:(?:\w+)=(?:\w+)\s*)*)$')
    line = re.split(" +", atString)
    formatList = regexFormat.search(line)
    if formatList:
            for param in formatList[0].split():
                    splitParam = param.split('=')
                    formatDictionary[splitParam[0]] = splitParam[1]

def setVariable (atString, varDictionary):
    regexVAR = re.compile(r'@(\w+)=(\w+|.*)\s*$', re.MULTILINE)
        # file = open(input)
        # line = file.readline()
        # line = re.split(" +", atString)
        #while line:
    varList = regexVAR.findall(atString)
    for key, value in varList:
        varDictionary[key] = value
```

Comment: I see you're using MULTILINE, but is the input file formatted so there's only one 'command' per line, or will they sometimes span multiple lines?

Comment: it's only one command per line @Todd

Comment: Also.. do you use an IDE to write your code? If you use PyCharm, you can set a breakpoint in the code that's having trouble, then step through it line by line in the debugger to isolate the problems.

Comment: ive actually already done that, it was broken over small parts and then i brought it all together. i'm just having trouble with those errors, idk if its because i'm not creating a right list, or string or what @Todd

Comment: This is what I think of as a "debug session" type question. It's difficult to eyeball code and debug, and probably you'd get more value out of getting familiar with the debugger of your IDE.

Comment: What is the condition that breaks your `while True:` loop? Also, you are reading a line `inputLine = file.readline()` at the beginning and at the end of the while loop, wouldn't that cause a line to be skipped?

Comment: @n1colas.m no, it isn't causing a line skip, and it has to do with how i'm reading in the file contents. its all being read as a list, instead of a string. but if i read it as one whole string, wouldn't that be bad? like, it wouldn't be able to read everything line by line like that?